# Interruped Gparted NTFS resize. Still have access to drive but GParted cannot read contents

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, gparted, ntfs

I have an external 1TB HDD (USB) formatted to NTFS, and wanted to shrink the partition about 300GB and create an ext4 partition. So I opened up GParted and done that. During the resize partition (I think around 50-60% of the "Moving" operations), another program on my computer crashed and forced me to restart Xorg.

The weird thing is that I still have access to my NTFS drive and can read and write to it with no problems, and if I open it in GParted while mounted it behaves normally (like no action happened). Except, if I unmount the drive, Gparted shows the NTFS partition as occupying the whole disk but cannot display how much is being used. (So I can no longer resize, etc). When right-clicking on the partition and choosing "Information", I get this warning:

```
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g.
```

But, like I said earlier, I have access to all the content on it through the file manager when it's mounted... Do you have any suggestions on what might be wrong?

PS: I'm running elementary (based on Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Does it have an operating system installed on the NTFS part or is it just files?

Comment: It's just files on an external HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, the NTFS partition's list of locations on the disk where the data for each file lies is correct. The fix under that condition is fairly easy if you can copy the files to a different drive. Here's how:

## Remount the drive read-only

The first thing to do is to stop all writing to the drive. Remount it read-only by opening a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run the following:

```
mount | fgrep media
```

It should tell you the external drives you have. For example, mine looks like this:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/username/EC-FLASH type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Make sure the mount point (the `/media/username/EC-FLASH` part in the example) is correct for your external drive. If it is, take the very first part (the `/dev/sdb1` part in the example), and run the following, replacing `/dev/sdb1` with what showed up for your drive:

```
sudo mount -o remount,ro /dev/sdb1
```

## Preserve the files

1. Check all the files that you care about. Take your time on this. Do they open? Are the contents correct?
2. If anything is messed up, STOP. Don't continue with this guide, as it won't be able to fix messed up files.
3. Copy the files to a different drive.

## Fix the external drive

1. In GParted, delete all partitions on the problematic external drive.
2. Create whatever partitions you want, making sure they get formatted.
3. Copy the files back to the NTFS partition.

Comment: Yeah, I had already thought of that. The problem is that I don't have space anywhere else to copy it to. 
A friend suggested running MiniTool Partition Wizard on Windows (My computer is dual-booted with Windows 8.1) and a basic disk check comes back with lots of errors of the type:

Attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 40666 is corrupt.

(The segment number changes on every error). 

I have no idea if I should get it to try and fix those errors or if that could harm more that it would help.

Comment: @TobySelway, stop trying to "fix" the partition until you have made a copy of the data first. If you don't have space, get a new drive (or decide if the data is less worth than a drive and you don't care about risking it).

Comment: Yeah, that's a better idea. I've already gone through a lot of old backups and stuff and deleted most of it that I don't need. I'll see if I can find some other drives for putting the rest on (It's still about 500GB, but luckily I found some old IDE and SATA 40GB-250GB HDDs here, so I'll put them in an enclosure and use them for the moment... The rest can be re-downloaded if needed).
Anyway, I'll reply once I've formatted it, to let you know if I've managed to "repair" the partitions after formatting.
Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.